# Classes and methods with PDO, and retrieving the data

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm new to OOP programming, and I'm really lost with this what the title says. When I try to put the query in a class and in another file, I get errors in a file called Main.php and don't even know what to do to fix them:

> Notice: Undefined variable: sth in Select.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in Select.php on line 10

If I put the select in Connection.php, it returns the rows just fine, but with classes, I get those.

Here's my code:

Connection.php:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

function connectDB ($hostname, $username, $password){
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=database", $username, $password);
    return $dbh;
}

$dbh = connectDB ($hostname, $username, $password);
echo 'Connected to database <br/>';
```

Select.php:

```
<?php require_once 'Connection.php';
class Select {

    public function select() {
        $sql= "select * from table limit 10; <br/>";
        echo $sql;
        $select = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        foreach($this->$sth as $row){
            echo $row['column']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I print the result from the query (for example from main.php, which has an autoloader), and why do I get those errors, when on a single file, they work just fine?

Edit:

```
<?php
    $test = new Select($dbh);
    echo $test->select();
?>
```

Besides the fixes in the replies, I included Connection.php into the main.php, changed the `echo` in Select.php to `return` and it works perfectly now. Adding this in case someone ever gets as lost as me.

Comment: `foreach($this->$sth as $row)` will be `foreach($this->$sql as $row)`. change `$sth` to `$sql`.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud Sorry, but that is nonsense. That class does not have a property `select * from table limit 10; <br/>`!

Comment: @arkascha sorry, i have already edit this. You are commenting before i edit it thats why you dont see my full reply.

Comment: You want your loop to iterate over the `$select` array.

Comment: And a general hint: this reads like you are trying to implement an abstraction layer for the abstraction layer. Millions of such attempts have been made, but this does not really make much sense. The abstraction `PDO` offers is perfectly fine. Your attempt _appears_ to be smart and save time, but you will find that it removes flexibility and adds complexity.

Comment: @arkascha Good to know. What do you suggest me to do instead? As I said, I'm new to OOP, and I guess it would be _really bad_ to get bad practices from the very beginning. Thank you very much for the help so far, by the way!

Comment: Just use PDO as it is, it is perfectly fine. Or, if you _really_ insist on some additional layer (why?), then take a look at one of the many frameworks that exist. Most do offer such layer. Ask yourself this question: what if I want to make a select but _not_ output the result via an echo?

Comment: @arkascha Makes sense. In theory it should grab the data from a form (probably using prepared statements), and do some statistics from the results, not print the query directly. The thing is that I can't even manage to do a simple query, and it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to iterate over the query, but the result of that query. So this probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
class Select {
    public function select() {
        $sql= 'select * from table limit 10';
        $select = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($select as $row){
            echo $row['column']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

And you also need to take care that the `$dbh` object is actually present inside that method. Either inject it into the object or specify it as method argument. So your full class will probably look something like that:

```
<?php
class Select {
    private $dbh;
    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }
    public function select() {
        $sql= 'select * from table limit 10';
        $select = $this->dbh->query($sql)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($select as $row){
            echo $row['column']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

And you instantiate the object like that:

```
$selectObj = new Select($dbh);
```

---

Some general warning, though: Using PDO's `fetchall()` method is convenient, but carries a huge risk: it means that the full result set has to be copied into an array inside the php script. For bigger results that may lead to issues with memory usage (scripts getting terminated for security reasons). Often it is the better approach to use a `while` loop over a single row fetched from the result set in each iteration.

Comment: This looks better than my actual code, but I still get "Notice: Undefined variable: dbh" and "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null" on select.php line 5 ($select = $dbh->query...).
Edit: How do I specify it as method argument? This OOP stuff is really confusing me.

Comment: I approve that you are introducing dependency injection whilst they are young. Top tip with OOP, it's way easier to manage if you pass what you need to your classes than "assume" they exist in global namespace. Consider anything "global" as bad practice.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, I edited my comment too fast, sorry! I forgot to put $dbh in "`$selectObj = new Select($dbh);`". It removed the fatal error, but I have now: "Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in main.php on line 19" (line 19 being where I have new Select($dbh)).

Comment: Well, you obviously have to define that variable _before_ injecting it. You showed your `Connection.php` script which does that. I assume you use it.